# Running multiple threads on the same DPDK lcore

Tags: c, dpdk

I am developing a dpdk forwarding application to receive and forward packets. I have two a functions to receive and forward packets from two ports. I called the function,
**rte_eal_remote_launch** to launch forwarding and receiving functions on two different lcores. This consumed two of the lcores of the lcore mask. Therefore I used service cores to launch both in the same lcore. I could get the two functions to receive and forward registered as services. But when I start the services, only one service runs.

The services were registered and mapped to the same lcore successfully. But only one runs at the runtime. Any clarification on this issue is appreciated.

The code for service registering and starting as follows.

```
 for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        uint32_t id;
        ret = rte_service_component_register(&services[i], &id);
        printf("service id : %d\n", id);
        if (ret)
                rte_exit(-1, "service register() failed");

        rte_service_component_runstate_set(id, 1);
        rte_service_set_stats_enable(id, 1);
        ret = rte_service_runstate_set(id, 1);
        if (ret)
                return -ENOEXEC;
}
printf("Service Components Registrations Done!\n");
ret = rte_service_lcore_add(core);
if(ret == 0)
    printf("Service core added\n");
if (ret && ret != -EALREADY)
    printf("core %d added ret %d\n", core, ret);

ret = rte_service_lcore_start(core);
if(ret == 0)
    printf("Service core started\n");
if (ret && ret != -EALREADY)
    printf("core %d start ret %d\n", core, ret);

for (int s = 0; s < 4; s=s+2) {
    if (rte_service_map_lcore_set(s, core, 1))
        printf("failed to map lcore %d\n", core);
    else{
        printf("Service %d started on core\n", s);
    }
```

Following is the result of `rte_service_dump` after delaying the system using `rte_delay_us_sleep(5 * US_PER_S);`

```
    Services Summary
  service_channel_in: stats 1   calls 0 cycles 0    avg: 0
  service_channel_out: stats 1  calls 0 cycles 0    avg: 0
  service_channel_in: stats 1   calls 0 cycles 0    avg: 0
  service_channel_out: stats 1  calls 0 cycles 0    avg: 0
Service Cores Summary
05  0   0   0   0
```

Comment: please share the following information 1) DPDK version, 2) code snippet for functions and sample code for service core launch 3) Sertivce core mask shared as real args 4) result for 1`rte_service_map_lcore_get ` and ` rte_service_dump`

Comment: thanks for replying. 1) 20.08  2) `for (int s = 0; s < 4; s=s+2) { if (rte_service_map_lcore_set(s, core, 1)) /*core = 1*/   printf("failed to map lcore %d\n", core); else{ printf("Service %d started on core\n", s); } }`. The functions for services are just simple forwarding and receiving using threads.   3) I did not use core mask as runtime args because I specify core number 1 inside the code.   4) All the services were mapped correctly.  `rte_service_map_lcore_set` returned 0.

Comment: please update the answers to the original question. It is difficult for others to follow the comments. With respect to service core mask there are internal checks in `rte_eal_init` which ensures none of the dataplane cores are used for service cores. Since you have not shared any core mask used for rte_eal_init, there is no set service cores. WIll look into this soon and share my observation or answer.

Comment: I am adding the service core dynamically in the application code itself. Therefore I did not pass a service core-mask as an EAL argument at startup time.

Comment: result of `rte_service_dump` is added to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DPDK API ***rte_eal_remote_launch*** can work different CPU cores as well as the same CPU core too.

1. on different CPU logical cores `-l 2-3`
2. to run on same CPU logical core `--lcore (0-1)@2`

note the second option will run create 2 DPDK threads '0-1' to run on CPU logical core `2`

based on the result for `rte_service_dump` there are 2 functions running namely ***service_channel_in and service_channel_out***

**Hence the observation about rte_remote_launch and rte_service not running on same CPU physical core is incorrect.**

sample code

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <signal.h>

#include <rte_eal.h>
#include <rte_cycles.h>
#include <rte_lcore.h>

volatile bool run = true;

int helloWaitTest(void *arg)
{
        uint16_t val = *(uint16_t *)arg;

        while(run)
        {
                printf(" val %u dpdk logical core %u logical core index %u\n", val, rte_lcore_id(), rte_lcore_index(rte_lcore_id()));
                rte_delay_ms(1000 + 1000 * val);
        }

        return 0;
}

static void
signal_handler(int signum)
{
        if (signum == SIGINT) {
                run = false;
        }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);

        /* Initialize the Environment Abstraction Layer (EAL). */
        int ret = rte_eal_init(argc, argv);
        if (ret < 0)
                rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "Error with EAL initialization\n");

        argc -= ret;
        argv += ret;

        uint16_t lcore_id = 0;
        RTE_LCORE_FOREACH_WORKER(lcore_id)
        {
                uint16_t temp = lcore_id;
                rte_eal_remote_launch(helloWaitTest, &temp, temp);
        }
        uint16_t temp = rte_lcore_id();
        helloWaitTest(&temp);

        rte_eal_mp_wait_lcore();
        /* clean up the EAL */
        rte_eal_cleanup();

        return 0;
}
```

How to run: `sudo ./a.out --lcores '(1-2)@3'`

Comment: Im sorry if I did not understand correctly. But does not the line `rte_eal_remote_launch(helloWaitTest, &temp, temp);` launches the function in every lcore except the master core? If so, what is the use of this argument `--lcores '(1-2)@3'` if all the lcores are running helloWaitTest already? Does that argument relieve any of the above used lcores?

Comment: please check https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/linux_gsg/linux_eal_parameters.html, as per DPDK documentation when one uses option `--lcores` it creates `n` threads on 1 CPU core.

Comment: Can you please explain what lcore stands for? and a reliable source to learn about dpdk

Comment: Hi @MeyerBuaharon I have already shared the source of information as https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/linux_gsg/linux_eal_parameters.html. Can you please explain in detail what you are asking for? I am available on skype.